# Jenkins Plugin Manager downloads one fails the rest

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins 2.346.2

java.runtime.version 11+28

Plugin Manager Update Site URL: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

Since a couple of weeks ago, on Jenkins (running on windows), when trying to update the plug-ins, it always downloads the first one but fails the rest. If I restart Jenkins and try again, the first one that failed before downloads OK; the rest fail.

> un.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)

From the picture below, JWT for Blue Ocean would download fine after I reboot, and the rest would fail... and so and so...

[image]

Comment: Added requested info to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, updating Java did the trick... I switched to Amazon Corretto 11.